# Is all Snort community rules available in Snort registered rules?

Tags: ids, snort, file-inclusion

I am working with snort. I have included both latest community and registered rules in my snort configuration file. During run time I found many rules have duplicated, that is some rules available in both community and registered rules. Thus my snort ignoring old duplicated rules.Because of this snort takes much time to come up. How to ignore these duplication ? or shall I include registered rules only in my snort? . Is all snort community rules available in snort registered rules ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is all snort community rules available in snort registered rules ?

Yes. `snort` Registered ruleset contains the Community ruleset. [Ref](https://www.snort.org/faq/what-are-the-differences-in-the-rule-sets)

> or shall I include registered rules only in my snort?

It is recommended that you use both the Registered Ruleset and the community ruleset, if you are not going to become a subscriber. [Ref](https://www.snort.org/faq/what-are-the-differences-in-the-rule-sets)

Comment: rootkea is right. Source: I am in charge of the rule sets and the website.

Comment: If registered rulesets contain all community rules then why is it recommended to use both? It increases the running time of snort to remove duplicate rules.

Comment: @JoelEsler can answer it better about the recommendation of using both the Community Ruleset and Registered Ruleset even though snort Registered ruleset contains the Community ruleset.

Comment: Any info on @LakshmiBalan's question?